# An amusing idiom about forgetfulness?

Tags: idiomatic-language

There is an idiom in Indian languages about forgetfullness.

> **A shepherd keeps a baby lamb under his armpit and searches for it the whole village**

Is there an equivalent and amusing idiom in English.?

I know**his memory is like a sieve**

Comment: There is "[out of sight, out of mind](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/out-of-sight-out-of-mind?topic=forgetting-and-forgetfulness)" although it is not a humorous saying.

Comment: Not a saying, but the image of "losing your glasses by leaving them on your head" is amusing. There is no fixed proverb, but this is a well known, and similar situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are the idioms:

- It goes in one ear and comes out the other (meaning you immediately forget what you hear)
- He's having a senior moment (meaning someone is having a lapse in memory, perhaps due to old age or *like* someone older)
- He's got a brain like swiss cheese (meaning full of holes)

The only equivalent I can think of that is similar to your lengthy Indian saying is a common comedic trope of someone searching for their spectacles which are on sitting on top of their head.

Comment: The first one is common in the language I know  and the second one is new and  lengthy tale is amusing.

Comment: @What does " commp" mean?

Comment: @Englishmonger That's what I was asking you, but I see you've edited your comment now.